# When to use derivedStateOf in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In my ViewModel I have

```
private val _topicsResponse = MutableStateFlow<Result<List<Topic>>>(Result.Initial)
val topicsResponse = _topicsResponse.asStateFlow()
```

I fetch data (topics) from the server and that's why the data is wrapped in `Result<T>` class. It can be `Result.Initial`, `Result.Loading`, `Result.Success` and `Result.Error`

In my compose function of topics screen I have the logic for displaying the error using Snackback

```
val topicsResponse: Result<List<Topic>> by topicsViewModel.topicsResponse.collectAsState()

Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    ...

    if (topicsResponse is Result.Error) {
        Snackbar(
            action = {
                Button(onClick = { topicsViewModel.loadTopics() }) {
                    Text(stringResource(id = R.string.retry_text))
                }
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(8.dp)
                .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
        ) { Text(text = "Test error message") }
    }
}
```

Is it good to use `topicsResponse is Result.Error` here?

Because I was reading about `derivedStateOf` at https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-advanced-state-side-effects?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fcompose%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fjetpack-compose-advanced-state-side-effects#8

So I'm not sure if I should use

```
val showSnackBarError by remember {
    derivedStateOf {
        topicsResponse is Result.Error
    }
}
```

or just `val showSnackBarError = topicsResponse is Result.Error`

`topicsViewModel.topicsResponse.collectAsState()` - `collectAsState` already has `remember` inside its implementation

but still `topicsResponse is Result.Error` is going to be calculated on each recomposition even if the result of this condition is going to be the same as I understand

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `topicsResponse is Result.Error` will be calculated on each recomposition, but if the result does not change - you shouldn't care about that at all. Practically, this "calculation" have no impact on performance.

You could use `remember` here and it would work, but `remember` itself has much bigger cost than `is` operation. So you would loose performance in that regard.

As to `derivedStateOf` - there is no point using it here. It is used to track multiple state changes

Answer (score 0):

**Consider a Example**

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colors.background)
                { Demo() }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Demo() {
    var currentValue by remember { mutableStateOf("Undefined") }
    val stateValidation = remember{ derivedStateOf { currentValue == "Disney" } }
    Log.d("POKEMON", "Demo composable triggered")
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center, horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Log.d("POKEMON", "Column composable triggered")
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically, horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            Log.d("POKEMON", "Row composable triggered")
            Button(onClick = { currentValue = "Netflix" }) { Text(text = "Netflix") }
            Button(onClick = { currentValue = "Disney" }) { Text(text = "Disney") }
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))
        if(stateValidation.value){
            Log.d("POKEMON", "Disney is displayed")
            Text(text = currentValue)
        }
        Log.d("POKEMON", "<------------------------->")
    }
}
```

- Here say a composable is composed as a result of composition, We can define a condition in such a way that the recomposition occurs only when the defined condition is met.
- Consider the example below where the composition occurs and as long we keep pressing the button netflix no matter how many times the recomposition does not take place.
- Also not that, When the recomposition occurs the particular compose is recomposed. The entire composable hierarchy is not recomposed.

**(Output-State): we have not clicked the disney button**

```
Demo composable triggered
Column composable triggered
Row composable triggered
<------------------------->
```

**(Output-State): As soon we press the disney button entire composable is recomposed and the additional log state meant is displayed.**

```
Demo composable triggered
Column composable triggered
Row composable triggered
<------------------------->
Demo composable triggered
Column composable triggered
Row composable triggered
Disney is displayed
<------------------------->
```

**Source**: [From my own article](https://medium.com/@devrath.dev595/different-ways-to-store-modify-and-use-variables-inside-composable-scopes-475eb4965e41)