# Item index inside rememberDismissState not being updated on list update in LazyColumn itemsIndexed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-flow, android-jetpack-compose-list

I have a `LazyColumn` with some items where you can only remove the first item in the list (index 0).

The `LazyColumn` looks something like this:

```
LazyColumn {
    itemsIndexed(items, key = { _, item -> item.id }) { index, item ->
        val dismissState = rememberDismissState(DismissValue.Default) { dismissValue ->
            if (index != 0 && dismissValue == DismissValue.DismissedToEnd) {
                someOtherStuff()
                false
            } else true
        }
        if (dismissState.isDismissed(DismissDirection.StartToEnd)) {
            delete(item)
        }
        MyItem(dismissState)
    }
}
```

The operation of `delete()`is fairly irrelevant, all you have to know is that it removes the list item from the room database table, which is observed by the ViewModel, thus making `items` smaller by one element.

The problem is, however, that `index` (and lastIndex) inside the `rememberDismissState` is not up-to-date with the actual index of the `itemsIndexed`. If I remove the first item in a list of 3 items, I won't be able to remove the first item again in the resulting list of two items, because the index of the new first item is still `1` (or so `rememberDismissState`thinks).

I know that most likely this has something to do with the `rememberDismissState` not being recalculated when the list changes, so how do I do that? A workaround would be to map the list to indices before putting it into `itemsIndexed`, but is there any way to make the code above "work properly"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After coming back to this problem a few months later, I realized the issue:

The `rememberDismissState` "remembers" the list state and does not recompute even when the list changes. Since I need this to happen to calculate `index` or `items.size`, I fixed it by converting `rememberDismissState` into a keyed remember, like such:

```
val dismissState = remember(items) { DismissState(DismissValue.Default) {...} }
```

Thus, the dismissState is also recalculated each time the list changes, which was needed for me to get the code in my initial question working.

Additionally you could use `derivedStateOf` [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73395446/4464680), but as discussed in that answer, semantically there is no difference.