# How to avoid recomposition if variable changed to certain value?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a variable that is remembered in code

```
val action = remember { mutableStateOf(Action.FRESH) }
```

action can have values of **(FRESH, SEARCH, IDLE)**

I want to avoid recomposition if action changed to **Action.IDLE**, but recompose normally for any other value..

I read the action value as follows:

```
val listOfItems = when (action) {
    Action.FRESH -> {
        action = Action.IDLE
        // Get Initial data from server
    }

    Action.SEARCH -> {
        action = Action.IDLE
        // Get Search data from server
    }

    else -> {
        // Do Nothing
    }
}
```

I don't want to recompose when action is IDLE so I won't have to set **listOfItems** with a empty value in the else branch...

I tried adding **key** to remember and also using **derivedStateOf** but nothing worked as expected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try **derivedStateOf {}**, is used when your state or key is changing more than you want to update your UI. It acts as a buffer for you, buffering out the changes you don't need. That is the primary difference between a keyed remember {} and derivedStateOf {}. With remember {}, you will still recompose as much as your key changes, which isn't a bad thing if that's what you need. If you don't need those recompositions though, that is where derivedStateOf {} comes in.

Take for example, showing a button only if the user has scrolled a LazyColumn.

val isVisible = lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex > 0
firstVisibleItemIndex will change 0, 1, 2 etc. as the user scrolls and cause a recomposition for every time it changes.

I only care about if it's 0 or not 0 and only want to recompose when that condition changes.

derivedStateOf is my buffer, it's buffering out all of those extra state changes I don't need and limiting the recomposition to only when the derivedStateOf changes.

```
val isVisible = remember { derivedStateOf { lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex > 0 } }
```

For the example given in the question, a remember(key1, key2) {} is the correct API to use there, not derivedStateOf {} because you want your UI to update any time the key changes, there isn't any change to buffer out.

I am attaching the link here [Compose: remember() with keys vs. derivedStateOf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70144298/compose-remember-with-keys-vs-derivedstateof)

Comment: "derivedStateOf" doesn't solve my issue as it doesn't prevent recomposition when action changes.
I updated my question for more clarification..

Comment: Well... "derivedStateOf" was indeed the solution to my issue...
But I had to use it along side with mutable state..
I will accept your answer...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is my final working code, In case any one needed it..

```
var action by remember { mutableStateOf(Action.FRESH) }
val actionNotIdle by remember { derivedStateOf { action != Action.IDLE } }

val listOfItems = if (actionNotIdle) {
    when (action) {
        Action.FRESH -> {
            action = Action.IDLE
            itemsViewModel.fetchItems().collectAsLazyPagingItems()
        }

        Action.SEARCH -> {
            action = Action.IDLE
            itemsViewModel.searchItems().collectAsLazyPagingItems()
        }

        else -> {
            // Initial value
            itemsViewModel.itemsFlow.collectAsLazyPagingItems()
        }
    }
} else {
    // Initial value
    itemsViewModel.itemsFlow.collectAsLazyPagingItems()
}
```

Now if action is FRESH or SEARCH, Composable will recompose and fire the fetch/search calls.
If action is IDLE, nothing happens and the itemsList is kept unchanged and view doesn't get reloaded.